# A jQuery code is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

Below is my HTML structure. I want to add css code in the 4th child div

```
  <div class="amazingcarousel-image">
    <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
  </div>
```

The normal CSS code will be like below

```
.amazingcarousel-image div:nth-child(4) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I want to add the above CSS using jQuery, I have added the below code

```
function tinda() {
    jQuery(".amazingcarousel-image div:nth-child(4)").css("cssText", "display: none !important;"); 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    tinda();
})
```

The problem is this code is working in Firefox nicely but not in Chrome. Please help

Comment: It shouldn't even be working in FF. `css("cssText", "display: none !important;")` should be `css("display", "none")`

Comment: Don't do `.css("cssText", ...)`. Use it correctly: `.css("display", "none")`.

Comment: @MikeC `.css()` won't accept `!important`

Comment: @j08691 Right, forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function tinda() {
    jQuery(".amazingcarousel-image div:nth-child(4)").addClass('hide'); 
}

.amazingcarousel-image div.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```